# How can I use the first derivative test in an optimization problem?

Tags: calculus, optimization

This is a short and simple one, but I've solved the following optimization problem:

> Find two numbers whose sum is $60$ and whose product is a maximum.

where $x$ and $y$ are variables.

Here's my work:

Sum = $60$, Product = $xy$

Solving for y:

$$60 - x = y$$
$$P = x(60 - x) = 60x - x^2$$
$$P' = 60 - 2x \Rightarrow  60 - 2x = 0 \Rightarrow x = 30$$
$$60 - x = y, y = 30$$

I'm not sure how exactly I can use the first derivative test to determine/prove the max/min. Max would be for this specific problem though.

How can I determine the maximum value by using the first derivative test when having only one critical point?

Comment: What do you mean $60 + y$? The sum is $60 = x + y$ and the product $xy$, right?

Comment: @js9 y is used as a placeholder for the unknown value that I needed to solve.

Comment: wouldn't $y$ be $0$ in that case? I believe you know what to do with the problem but your problem formulation seems strange to me.

Comment: No because you need to find both x and y.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to make your question easier to read.

Comment: @Ten, well, your first constraint stated is: "Sum $= 60 + y$" and in your solution you have $y = 30$, hence the sum constraint is violated...(sum = 90)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $f'(x) = 60 - 2x$. Using a sign diagram:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c} x & 0 & 30 & 60 \\ \hline
f'(x)& + & 0 & - \end{array}$$

and since the derivative goes from positive to negative (sketch this out), you have a local maximum.

Alternatively, using the second derivative test $f''(x) = -2$, and when $f''(x)$ is negative, you have a local maximum (think of a sad face).

It's worth noting that you do not need calculus: find the axis of symmetry of the parabola, then substitute that value in. Quadratics with a negative $x^2$ term are always concave up.

Comment: Yes thank you! That's what I had been looking for!

Comment: @Ten No problem!

Comment: Question, did you use 60 because it was a given? If not, why did you use 60 as the x value?

Comment: Any values of $x$ will work as long as they are on either side of the critical point. $x = 0$ makes the calculation easier, but $x = 60$ is just arbitrary: you could use $x = 40, 50$ and so on.

Comment: Okay thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[Here is one relevant statement of the First Derivative Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_test#Precise_statement_of_first-derivative_test).

In your case, you have found that $P'(30)=0$. You can also observe that $P'(x) > 0$ when $x\in(0,30)$, and that $P'(x) < 0$ when $x\in(30,60)$. The First Derivative Test then tells you that $x=30$ is a local maximum.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is as follows:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\max_{x,y} xy\\
\textrm{s.t.} \quad & x+y = 60\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

By a simple substitution, you let $x = 60 - y$. Your problem now becomes an unconstrained optimization problem:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\max_{y} \quad 60y-y^2\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

When is this maximum? Take your first derivative test. You also have a sufficiency condition using your second derivative test.

Also, take for instance, the parabola function, you only have one critical point and it is indeed a maximum/or minimum.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach.  Since $x$ and $y$ sum to $60$, the problem can be re-interpreted as assuming that $x = 30 + k$, $y = 30 - k$, and you want to maximize $xy = (30 + k)(30 - k) = 900 - k^2.$